# Working with Google IMA android sdk onAdsLoaded function is being called only once

Tags: android

to add the listeners im doing:

```
 mAdsManager.addAdErrorListener(this);
 mAdsManager.addAdEventListener(this);
```

and the onAdsLoaded:

```
 @Override
 public void onAdEvent(AdEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
    case CONTENT_PAUSE_REQUESTED:
        pause();
        break;
    case CONTENT_RESUME_REQUESTED:
        resume();
        break;
    case CLICK:
        mAdsManager.unload();
        break;
    }
}
```

the function is being called once for CONTENT_PAUSE_REQUESTED but after that when I press on the prperoll for example and the CLICK event should be fired it doesnt (and the error function is not being called also).

am i missing something? cant find anything on the net regarding this issue.

Comment: How can we get data parsed by VAST?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, didnt call the callback in the right place.

Comment: i got same issue, which is called only once, how to resolve this?

Comment: Hi, sorry it was too long ago i'm not entirely sure what i did, but if ill remember ill post it.

Comment: oh thanks for your response @adi ohaion,  can u pls send ur email id for further clarification if u dont mind?